# Arrays not equal

Tags: javascript, d3.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to load a csv file with d3 and am trying to create a drop-in replacement for the explicit 2D array (named iris_2).  When comparing the two 2D arrays with underscore.js (using _.isEqual), I noticed that they are not equal ([check out the Codepen.io code](https://codepen.io/scottlittle/project/editor/ZWrbQD/#0)). What's even stranger is that if I use _.isEqual to compare them when inspecting the html page, it says they are equal.

Here's the d3 code:

```
var iris = [];
d3.csv("data/iris.csv", function(mydata) {
    mydata.forEach(function(d) {
        d["sepal_length"] = +d["sepal_length"];
        d["sepal_width"] = +d["sepal_width"];
        d["petal_length"] = +d["petal_length"];
        d["petal_width"] = +d["petal_width"];
        iris.push([d["sepal_length"], d["sepal_width"], d["petal_length"], d["petal_width"], d["species"]]);
    });
});
```

Here's the first five data lines of the iris.csv file with the header that I want to read with d3:

```
sepal_length,sepal_width,petal_length,petal_width,species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
...
```

Here's the first five lines of the "explicit" 2D array:

```
var iris_2 = [
  [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
  [4.9, 3.0, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
  [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2, 'setosa'],
  [4.6, 3.1, 1.5, 0.2, 'setosa'],
  [5.0, 3.6, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'] ...
```

This is the underscore.js code I was using to compare the two arrays:

```
_.isEqual(iris, iris_2);
```

This returns false for the html code (see above Codepen link), but true for the Chrome html inspector console.

Comment: Instead of using `+d[…]` try using `1*d[…]`. That may help to eliminate the possiblity of interpreting the data as strings.

Comment: @Manngo - the `+` (unary plus) in the OP's code is already converting to number.

Comment: @nnnnnn You’re right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d3.csv` is **asynchronous**. This means that, by the time you get to...

```
document.getElementById("myValue").innerHTML = _.isEqual( iris, iris_2 );
```

... there is still **no** `iris` array (or, more precisely, it's still empty), and the result is `false`.

However, if you compare the arrays **inside** the callback, giving time to `d3.csv` populating your `iris` array...

```
d3.csv("iris.csv", function(mydata) {
    mydata.forEach(function(d) {
        d["sepal_length"] = +d["sepal_length"];
        d["sepal_width"] = +d["sepal_width"];
        d["petal_length"] = +d["petal_length"];
        d["petal_width"] = +d["petal_width"];
        iris.push([d["sepal_length"],
            d["sepal_width"],
            d["petal_length"],
            d["petal_width"],
            d["species"]
        ]);
    });

    var iris_2 = [
        [5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2, 'setosa'],
        ...
    ];

    document.getElementById("myValue").innerHTML = _.isEqual(iris, iris_2);
    //comparing inside the callback

});//callback ends here
```

... you'll see that the result is `true`.

Actually, "giving time" to `d3.csv` populating `iris` array is what explains what you said:

> What's even stranger is that if I use _.isEqual to compare them when inspecting the html page, it says they are equal.

That happens because, when you inspect the page, `iris` array has been already created.

You can check the working code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/24CypznlScazjcqGKsCq?p=preview